# Handling Push Notifications when the app is open

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I'm building a mobile chat app. I've configured OneSignal to send push notifications to my iOS device.

I plan to send push notifications to the user when a new message is received and the application isn't in the foreground (similar to how Facebook Messenger works).

I'm new to push notifications. I can imagine two solutions, neither of them elegant:

**Solution 1:** Send a push notification every time a message is sent. Then, if the app is open, ignore/swallow the notification. (Seems like a waste of resources).

**Solution 2:** Keep track of the app's state in my own database and only send a push notification if the app isn't in the foreground. (Seems overly complex).

What am I missing? What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: I think solution 1 is how you should handle the push notification. For the second approach you need to communicate to the server every time your app changes state.

Comment: It's all about how to handle push notifications. You should go with solution 1.